# How to dereference typedef array pointer properly?

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

I am using 3rd party code, which has type defined as:

```
typedef float MarkerData[3];
```

later in the code, I have array of this marker position data referenced as:

```
MarkerData* Markers;
```

I am using this code to iterate this array:

```
for (int32 s = 0; s < totalMarkers; s++)
{

MarkerData* mData = (Markers + s);

markerPosition.X = *(mData)[0];
markerPosition.Y = *(mData)[1];
markerPosition.Z = *(mData)[2];


}
```

The code does not crash, but float values get mixed. From debug I can see, that I properly get markerPosition.X value on every iteration, but Z and Y are taken from other array. I suppose I am using wrong pointer arithmetic here, but no matter what, can not figure it out. This typedef really is new to me, and I don't know - what might be off?

Comment: `int32 s = 0;` should be `size_t s = 0;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's debatable and may depends on the type of `totalMarkers`.

Comment: totalMarkers type is int32

Comment: Can you please provice a [MCVE] along with a comparison between the results you obtained and the results you expected? It's hard to definitively know what you did wrong with such little information.

Comment: Understood, if that explanation is not enough, I will submit MCV example

Comment: I have a *strong* suspicion that you intended your format of `*(mData)[0]` to be `(*mData)[0]`. And "does not crash" should never be equated with "is correct". Running this through Valgrind would *likely* flag read-violations.

Comment: The parentheses on `(mData)` **do not do anything**. `*(abc)[splat]` means exactly the same thing as `*abc[splat]`.  Parentheses have to enclose two or more tokens of syntax in order to actually perform *grouping*, thereby influencing the parse of the syntax.  The exception would be something like `#define mData badly + behaved`, where the macro writer forgot parentheses, so the caller needs them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug caused by a misunderstanding of [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Operators have an order in which they are applied. This is similar to operator precedence in mathematics where, for example, multiplication has a higher priority than addition. `operator*` (dereferencing operator) has lower precedence than `operator[]` (subscript operator). What this means is the expression `*(mData)[2]` is parsed as "dereference the third element at pointer `mData`". The third element is presumably an array of 3 floats (if you haven't exceeded the bounds of the array pointed to by `mData`). You then dereference that resulting array. Dereferencing an array gives you the first element in that array. In essence you are fetching the first element of different markers over and over again. You can alter precedence using parentheses. Try `(*mData)[0]` instead. This will force the dereferencing of your pointer first, giving you the array of `float`s which is then accessed by index with the subscript operator.

```
for (int32 s = 0; s < totalMarkers; s++)
{
    MarkerData* mData = (Markers + s);

    markerPosition.X = (*mData)[0];
    markerPosition.Y = (*mData)[1];
    markerPosition.Z = (*mData)[2];
}
```

Most of your troubles could have been avoided with the use of proper c++ containers such as [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: No, the misunderstanding is not just tabout precedence. There is the misundertsanding that the parentheses in `(mData)` do anything different from just `mData` (in the ordinary case, when  `mData` isn't a badly behaving macro).